# Rails 3 Postfix sending / receiving emails on same server using gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmail, google-apps, postfix-mta

We have a rails 3 application running on vps using postfix for sending email. All emails for this domain name are hosted on Google Apps.  All emails sent to domains other than the domain the app is hosted on are sending properly but the emails using the same domain return a bounceback saying the address is an unknown user because postfix thinks the emails are being sent locally.

Does anyone know the proper settings / configuration for postfix to enable the sending of emails to Google Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following line in /etc/postfix/main.cf (might look different on your system):

```
mydestination = yourdomain.com, localhost.yourdomain.com, localhost
```

to:

```
mydestination = localhost
```

or even:

```
mydestination =
```

And restart postfix: `/etc/init.d/postfix restart`